# Coloring an edge detected image by user input co-ordinates..??What's wrong with this code?

Tags: python

I need to color the white part surrounded by black edges!

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
image=Image.open("G:/ghgh.bmp")
data=image.load()

image_width,image_height=image.size   

sys.setrecursionlimit(10115)

def f(x,y):
    if(x<image_width and y<image_height and x>0 and y>0):
        if (data[x,y]==255):
            image.putpixel((x,y),150) 
            f(x+1,y)
            f(x-1,y)
            f(x,y+1)
            f(x,y-1)
            f(x+1,y+1)
            f(x-1,y-1)
            f(x+1,y-1)
            f(x-1,y+1)
f(100,100)
image.show()
```

255 is to detect white color, 150 is used to re-color greyish, and (100,100) is the starting pixel.

It's giving "Max recursion depth" at n=10114 and python crashes on n=10115 (the `setrecursionlimit(n)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's up with the `while` loop? It never changes the coordinates, so it seems it would loop forever, doing recursive calls. From a quick reading it sounds like it should be a plain `if`.

Also: drop the parens with `while` and `if`; they're not needed in Python.

Comment: While loop always gets the x's and y's updated beacause functions are called like if i pass f(100,100) now x=100 y=100 but in recursion f(101,100) is called so now x=101,y=100

Comment: But you don't want to loop! You're using recursion, and there's nothing *at a given level of recursion* to change the values of x and y so the loop is not needed.

Comment: hmm...maybe,,BUt if you remove the loop it says"index out of range" cause the pointer went to a pixel that doesn't exist..

Comment: As I say in my answer (please read it again), you should probably replace the while with an if, to get the test. Then you can also remove the inner if, with the break since it won't be necessary.

Comment: Even after replacing while with if the recursion set value has only decreased to n=9867, there's some other problem I guess

Answer (score 1):

"unwind" above is right. Just replace your "while" with an "if" and it should work.